# What is the difference between src and background of ImageView

Tags: android, background, imageview, src

I am a puzzled about using `src` or `background` for an `ImageView`.

I know the former means the content of this `ImageView` and the latter means the background of the `ImageView`.

But how to decide which one to use? I don't see the difference.

Answer (score 78):

All views can take a background image.

The `src` to an `ImageView` has additional features:

- different [scaling types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)
- `adjustViewBounds` for setting bounds to match image dimensions
- some transformations such as alpha-setting

And more that you may find in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Answer (score 28):

1. when you use `android:background`, image will be set to fit on `ImageView` area(i.e according to width and height of `ImageView`). It doesn't matter if the image is smaller or larger than `ImageView`.
2. when you use `android:src`, then image will display in its original size. No
   automatic scaling, adjustments will happen.
   **Note**: Using android:src, we can get additional benefit of adjustViewBounds property

Answer (score 22):

If you set an image to be the background of your ImageView, then the image will scale to whatever size the ImageView is. Other than that, src is a foreground image and background is a background image. Pretty much as it implies.

Comment: Why does an ImageView need a foreground **and** a **background**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky so that we can set overlays for different states like focused, pressed, etc.

Comment: @dgngulcan Material Components library does all of that built in.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky once upon a time ago, there wasn't a material components library :)

Answer (score 3):

***The difference between XML attribute src and background in ImageView:***

The background will stretch according to the length given by the *ImageView* component, and *SRC* will hold the size of the original image without stretching. *SRC* is the picture content (foreground), *BG* is the background, can be used at the same time.

***In addition***: *ScaleType* only works on SRC; *BG* can set transparency, *for example,* in *ImageButton*, you can use *Android:scaletype* to control how the image is scaled, sample code as follows:

```
 <ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/img"
  android:layout_height="60dip"
  android:layout_width= "60dip"
  android:src="@drawable/logo" 
  android:scaleType="centerInside" 
  android:layout_centerVertical= "true"/>
```

Feel free to ask doubt if you get any.