# Difference: android:background and android:src?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between src and background of ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454491/what-is-the-difference-between-src-and-background-of-imageview)

What is the difference between `android:background` and `android:src`? Is their working same?

Answer (score 14):

`android:background` exists for all the view. As the name suggests this is what is going to be there in the background.

`android:src` exists for `ImageViews` and its subclasses. You can think of this as the foreground. Because `ImageView` is a subclass of `View` you even have `android:background` for that.

- If the foreground is smaller than background, the background portion which is not covered by the foreground would be visible.
- Also, you can use transparency in the foreground in which case the background would be visible(transparently).

Answer (score 1):

You can use BACKGROUND FOR ALL THE VIEWS..
But You can use SRC only for ImageView & ImageButton.....

Answer (score -1):

one sets the background, one sets the image. You can use both to set a background to an image.