# Android button stretched in 4.1 but not in 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-version

I have a simple to-do list app with a button in the shape of a black plus to add things to the list.  In android 2.2, the black plus looks like this:

[image]

However, in android 4.1, the black plus looks like this:

[image]

The plus is supposed to look the way it does in 2.2. Here is my xml for the appropriate fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget78"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/taskslist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget83"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/taskname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:hint=" Add Something :)"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:layout_weight="9999999"/>
<!--    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine" 
    --> 
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/addtask"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/small_black_plus"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:text="" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why do the layouts look different on the two versions? How can I make them look the same?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this might have something to do with the way you're managing your resource files.  Do the devices that you tested on have different resolutions?  The distortion you see could be caused by the OS automatically scaling a resource that you put in your drawable-mdpi or drawable-hdpi folders for an xhdpi screen.

Here is a great reference for how to manage your resource files, hope this helps:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Edit:

Additionally, take a look at this question:

[Difference: android:background and android:src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458774/difference-androidbackground-and-androidsrc)

As was touched on by others, you could try changing your Button to an ImageView.  Any view in android can be used as a button by setting an onClickListener in the same way you would with a Button.  If you do this, try setting your image drawable resource with the `android:src` attribute instead of `android:background`.  I don't think that this is the cause of your problem because I'm not sure different versions of Android would cause your view to be different sizes, but perhaps between these two ideas you can figure out something that works.

Comment: I've tested on a Galaxy Nexus with ICS, an LG Lucid with Gingerbread, and two emulators. The screenshots I posted were from the emulators. However, the 2.2 emulator picture looks the same as on the lucid, and the 4.1 emulator looks the same as on the nexus. The emulators both say "hw.lcd.density: 240" but I don't know what that means. The nexus obviously has a much larger screen than the lucid, as well a settings button on the actionbar.

Comment: You're probably right about my managing resource files incorrectly. I was just using one image for all screen sizes. I have since created 4 images, one for each screen size. Nevertheless, the android 4 version still looks stretched. I will read over your material more carefully and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the new TabHost in 4.1 allows for "scrollable" tabs.  See how you can scroll it horizontally?

In order to make this look correct on both versions of Android, I would create a ViewStub using resource qualifiers (in the folder name) for the different API levels, and use identical IDs for the different tabs, but explicitly set your font sizes where they don't fit (or change the text, that's up to you)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use an ImageView instead of the Button, they work the same in your case.