# Image from camera appearing too stretched inside imageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to click a photo using the camera, and then display it in imageView. Initially, the image looked extremely small, and did not fit in the imageView. However, after reading a couple of blogs, I made the following change to the code:

```
photo = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr,Uri.fromFile(tempPhoto));
//image.setImageBitmap(photo);
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo);
image.setBackground(drawable);
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

My Layout file is as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:background="@color/translucent_grey"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint_location"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="14sp" >

            <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="200dp" >
     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/snap"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
         android:background="@color/white"
         android:src="@drawable/camera" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:orientation="horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>     

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/datetime_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/eventDetails_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

After adding this, the image stretches too much, and looks quite elongated. I am aiming to fit the image on the screen width, and then have flexible image height so that the scale can be maintained (just the way fb modile displays portrait and landscape images fitting along the width of the screen)

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

use this parameter for ImageView

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

And then try to set height of imageView programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

use parameter

```
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code you should not use fill parent in spite use wrap content.

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/image"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"//fill_parent
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"//fill_parent
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Comment: Hi, I am wondering if specifying height 200dp to Relative Layout is stretching out the image..do you know how I should define the height of the Relative Layout

Comment: Why you are specifying height as a 200dp ?? if don't want to stretch make it as a wrap_content.

Comment: even after I do wrap_content, it appears stretched

Comment: make wrap_content to both height and width of relative layout and check.

Comment: Hi David, I did tht. Still no change

Answer (score 0):

Generally for the `ImageView` use `setImageDrawable(drawable);` because the ImageView it self take cares about the **scaling and streching** and you can use **scaleType** according to your requirement

Comment: Could you tell me what is the code for it..how is it different from what i have done already

Comment: you used **setBackground()** this resembles to BackGround, Where as **setImageDrawable** resembles to the src of the imageview..check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454491/what-is-the-difference-between-src-and-background-of-imageview

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
 photo = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, Uri.fromFile(tempPhoto));
 //image.setImageBitmap(photo);
 Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), photo);
 image.setBackground(drawable);
 image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/snap"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="160dp"
         android:background="@color/white"
         android:src="@drawable/camera" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
         android:orientation="horizontal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my output:
[image]

Comment: set height of image view to something appropriate value like android:layout_height="300dp"