# Android Studio, wrap ImageView size around the x and y scale of the actual image

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` with a mail icon, however, it was too big so **i reduced its size.**
**The actual size of the image is smaller, but the content it wraps is still the same**, resulting in my lines not being even. The image below demonstrates my problem

[image: showcase]

As you can see, the size of the imageview does not wrap around the image itself. 
Below is the XML for the imageview

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_mail"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"/>
```

**Is there a way to fix this?**

Below this is the full XML for the whole layout if that would help

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:background="@color/PaleGrey">

<Space
    android:id="@+id/dummyTopSpaceSc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/dummyTopSpaceSc"
    android:text="name"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameTextView"
    android:text="title"/>

<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:id="@+id/phoneContainer">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_phone"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phoneTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:text="phone"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>


<!-- below this comment is the container for the mail icon -->

<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mailContainer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/phoneContainer">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_mail"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="15%"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:text="email"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

<Space
    android:id="@+id/dummyBottomSpaceSc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/mailContainer"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does the image have a space?? try removing the scale.

Comment: if i remove the scale, it takes up the whole area, but then it looks too big

Comment: Then you need to specify the dimension or recreate the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should resize your image by giving it exact values for width and height instead of `wrap_content` if you actually want the bounding box to get smaller as you change the size. Then you can add padding/margins back to it as you wish. Also, you should use the `android:src` attribute (or maybe even [app:srcCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624554/android-what-is-the-difference-between-appsrccompat-and-androidsrc)) instead of `android:background`.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_mail" />
```

Comment: thank you, what is the benefit of using src over background?

Comment: `background` is a attribute of the `View` base class, while `src` is an attribute of `ImageView` which you're meant to use. I assume that using `background` instead will lead to some odd behaviour eventually. Setting the `src` attribute is equivalent to calling `setImageDrawable` from Java code. Good summary here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5454564/4465208