# src and background clips image content Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I get some images of our new designer but found it strange some of them look like this:

[image]

I'm trying to overcome it as it displays well on his device and normal image viewer or PC so while I try I found that if I used `src` if fit one that has clipped from the right and left (this while using background)

[image]

however, if I used src it get fit correctly.
[image]

some others (using background)

[image]

also, I used `src` it fits correctly.

I'm confused about this issues and can't find a clarification for it when I googled it.

Code For `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/aa"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/a123"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Hope anyone can suggest me a way to handle them programmatically and how to persuade designer it is from him if it is?

Hope also someone declares me the core of when using `src` or `background`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is your problem exactly.

However,`background`is for simply defining a shape,color,pattern or anything for our View or Layout.

So you can use this attribute for every layout and button or TextView or anything.

Let's say you have created a Circle.xml file which is a shape.If you call `background="@drawable/circle"` you can make your ImageView to have a Circular shape.

With `src` in an ImageView for example you put your Image in the ImageView.

You also can adjust the height and width of the displayed image by `layout_width` or `layout_height` which you can set both to "Wrap_content" or "match_parent" or any value

For fitting the image the way you want you should play with layout height and width and layout margin values!

Comment: please read the question again... I face an issue of clipped space can you see the background in the image from top and bottom right and left

Comment: Changing all the layout_widths to "match_parent" would do the trick.

Comment: lol, do you know ConstrainLayout? 0dp mean it will take the matcg_parent due to constraints please check code again

Answer (score 0):

1) I was facing the same issue i fixed it by using `android:scaleType="fitXY"` it will fit the image accordingly but if you use too small image it will be distorted and if you 
   will use raw image file make sure to use [Compressed image](https://tinypng.com/) without disturbing the 
   image quality.

2) All views can take a background image.

The `src` to an `ImageView` has additional features:

- different [scaling types](https://tinypng.com/)
- `adjustViewBounds` for setting bounds to match image dimensions
- some transformations such as alpha-setting

And more that you may find in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454491/what-is-the-difference-between-src-and-background-of-imageview)